# Tiny web server without compressed transfer encoding

Tags: http, compression, gzip, chunked, http-chunked

I am working on a very constrained device that has TCP support, and I want to support HTTP/1.1 but eliminate all of the compression support to make it fit the device limitations.

If a client sends compressed transfer encoding, which HTTP response status should be returned by the server to indicate it only accepts non-compressed chunks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [RFC 7230, section 3.3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.3.1):

> A server that receives a request message with a transfer coding it does not understand SHOULD respond with 501 (Not Implemented).

For *content codings* consult [RFC 7231, section 3.1.2.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.1.2.1):

> An origin server MAY respond with a status code of 415 (Unsupported Media Type) if a representation in the request message has a content coding that is not acceptable.